# How can I power these LEDs?

Tags: voltage, dc, led-driver

I'm trying to build myself a binary clock with a NodeMCU v3 and I am trying to figure out a way to power everything.

I'm trying to use these [Pololu 5 V RGB LEDs](https://www.pololu.com/product/2535). They are 5 V, 50 mA LEDs. I need 20 of them (6 for hours, 7 for minutes, 7 for seconds).

If I understand correctly, if I want to power them in series, I need 20 x 5 V = 100 V. Series is desirable because the data pins are daisy chainable so it would be fairly trivial to wire the DOUT and GND of one LED to the DIN and VIN of another. However, 100 V seems like a lot?

I could split them into banks, two banks of 7 and one of 6, which reduces the max but I still need 7 x 5 V = 35 V max.

I've tried to build myself a little LED driver out of an LM317T and a 9 V, 2 A supply, but the most I have got a single LED to do out of this is flash when I turn the power on and then nothing else.

Ideally I would like to power everything off of a 5 V USB supply, but I have the 9 V supply so that is an option.

Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to design the circuit in series or is this possible?

Comment: You don't want to power them in series. If you do so, the communication will not work. Connect their power in parallell, it requires a third wire but at least it will work.

Comment: To control those LEDs you will need MCU. They have some NRZ interface, similar to WS2811. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JZmgodDWtmU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Pololu files](https://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J5433.631.jpg?cdc0daa0c2fd98e38ed59b7d43758c6b).*

- The GND pins all have to be connected to supply common.
- The 5 V pins all have to be connected to supply +5 V.
- The DIN (data in) pins are all connected together and the data signal is referenced to GND.

> If I understand correctly, if I want to power them in series, I need 20 x 5 V = 100 V.

No. That won't work for several reasons. Ignoring the data problems for a moment, magine that one of the LEDs is off then no current would flow through the circuit and no other LEDs could turn on.

[image]

*Figure 2. LEDs lit up.*

The LEDs are designed to run directly from a 5 V supply. With RGB all on the LED will draw 50 mA so twenty will draw 1000 mA. A simple 5 V USB power supply would do the trick. Most are capable of least 2 A.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid using them in parallel to simplify the wiring but I hadn't considered what would happen if one turned off.

Comment: You also hadn't considered how to raise the data voltage for each DIN to be above the GND voltage of each LED. It should be clear now. Thanks for accepting this answer.